# How do I install boost-mpi and it's dependecies for clang on Mac OS?

Tags: c++, boost, mpi, clion, macos-catalina

I've been trying to install boost-mpi on MAC OS for clang, but I failed. Can anyone help me?
I tried:
`brew install open-mpi`
`brew install boost`
`brew install boost-mpi`
But I got this CMake error:

```
CMake Warning at /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_mpi-1.72.0/libboost_mpi-variant-shared.cmake:64 (message):
  Target Boost::mpi already has an imported location
  '/usr/local/lib/libboost_mpi-mt.dylib', which will be overwritten with
  '/usr/local/lib/libboost_mpi.dylib'
```

I tried to run MPI Hello world program ad got this error output:

```
Assertion failed: (_check_result == MPI_SUCCESS), function recv_impl, file /usr/local/include/boost/mpi/communicator.hpp, line 1400.
[Deniss-MacBook-Pro:83252] *** Process received signal ***
[Deniss-MacBook-Pro:83252] Signal: Abort trap: 6 (6)
[Deniss-MacBook-Pro:83252] Signal code:  (0)
[Deniss-MacBook-Pro:83252] [ 0] 0   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff6a5b95fd _sigtramp + 29
[Deniss-MacBook-Pro:83252] [ 1] 0   ???                                 0x0000000000000180 0x0 + 384
[Deniss-MacBook-Pro:83252] [ 2] 0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff6a48f808 abort + 120
[Deniss-MacBook-Pro:83252] [ 3] 0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff6a48eac6 err + 0
[Deniss-MacBook-Pro:83252] [ 4] 0   MPI                                 0x0000000100616af6 _ZNK5boost3mpi12communicator9recv_implIiEENS0_6statusEiiRT_N4mpl_5bool_ILb1EEE + 214
[Deniss-MacBook-Pro:83252] [ 5] 0   MPI                                 0x00000001006167f0 _ZNK5boost3mpi12communicator4recvIiEENS0_6statusEiiRT_ + 48
[Deniss-MacBook-Pro:83252] [ 6] 0   MPI                                 0x00000001006166f2 main + 114
[Deniss-MacBook-Pro:83252] [ 7] 0   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff6a3c0cc9 start + 1
[Deniss-MacBook-Pro:83252] [ 8] 0   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
[Deniss-MacBook-Pro:83252] *** End of error message ***
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this and make Hello world program work?
UPD 1: I managed to fix CMake warnings with `set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED TRUE)` in my CMakeLists.txt, but program still crashes. I think this is an issue with Mac OS Catalina: It asks for permission to recieve a network connection for the compiled program on every run. Do anyone knows how to deal with this problem?
UPD 2: I tried to turn the firewall off, and it didn`t ask for accepting incoming connections, but still fails with same error.

Comment: Have you checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58081084/target-boostlibrary-already-has-an-imported-location-link-errors) about the warning message similar to one you have got?

Comment: It removed CMake warnings, but the program still crashes

Comment: If you want to stick to `clang`, then you are probably fine with your answer and you can skip the rest of this comment. If you want to use `gcc` instead, but are afraid of building it for `macOS`, you can use this one: https://www.owsiak.org/building-opencoarrays-on-macos-everything-from-the-sources-gcc-9-2-0/ and this one: https://www.owsiak.org/modules-as-a-convenient-way-of-choosing-build-chain-on-macos/

Comment: @Oo.oO Why using `gcc` with mpi is better than `clang`? I\`m new to MPI, so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: @DenisIvanenko I don't claim it's better. But I am pretty sure it is way more common to have `OpenMPI` installed together with `gcc` on HPC machines. So, eventually, when you decide to bring your computations into HPC world it will turn out that everything is `gcc` based there. This is why I prefer to work with `gcc` based codes on my macOS - when it comes to MPI based codes.

Comment: Okay, thank`s for the explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it all. Actually, my error consists of a bunch of things. Firstly, as I found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58081084/target-boostlibrary-already-has-an-imported-location-link-errors), `set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED TRUE)` helps to remove CMake warnings. But then the issue with program warnings was because CLion doesn`t run mpi program with `mpirun`. But then there is other warning with `mpirun` program run. This warning can be fixed with `export PMIX_MCA_gds=hash`. I found this solution [here](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/7516).